# Applying formula every other 6 cells in each row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, excel-2007, data-entry

[image: Excel Formula]

I'm applying this formula every other six cells, and dragging it down.

[image: Dragging formula down to the six cells]

I'm entering the formula manually.

Is there a much more faster way of applying this formula every other six cells?

Comment: That depends on what is in the 5 columns between the ones that you want to put the formula in.

Answer (score 0):

If it's basically the same formula, you can

- enter the formula into the first cell
- copy down
- copy all the formulas in the column
- go six columns to the right and paste
- repeat the last step as often as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Since its a simple formula of just cell plus cell, try this;

```
=IF((MOD(ROW(C2)-ROW($C$1)-1,6))=0,(C2-D4),"")
```

If you need the cells in between to actually be blank instead of just showing as blank probably have to go with VBA.

[image: Formula]